# How do I control the format in which MS-SQL Server returns datetime values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Specifically, I wish to get the date format in a pure (ISO) format:

YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

I'm looking for a SET command or something that I can use.

I do not wish to rely on the culture setting of the server.

Note: I'm interested in the string format in which dates are returned, not entered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the default format you need to add a new language (sp_addlanguage), set it's date format, then set the default language to it.  More details can be found on this old [technet article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907).

If you don't want to do that, then you can change it "per connection" using [SET DATEFORMAT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx).

And if you don't want to do that, then you can use [CONVERT](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) to convert it to the relevent format string in each query.

Comment: SET DATEFORMAT isn't much help as it's only for inputting dates.  The same things seems to be true about the language setting?  Input only, no ouput?

Comment: Well the SQL DateTime type is a DateTime type, it's not a string of a particular format. Maybe you need to be looking at your client code?

Comment: We're talking PHP here - I only have raw string access.  .Net of course parses the string to a DateTime, but no such luck with PHP.

Comment: Then CONVERT is probably your only option unfortunately, or abstract your data access away and convert all the dates in there.

Comment: Oh well :(  Damn Microsoft - date formatting is an application job, not database :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a handy article I found:

http://www.sqljunkies.ddj.com/Article/6676BEAE-1967-402D-9578-9A1C7FD826E5.scuk

What you're looking for is:

```
CONVERT(datetime,'05/08/2004',120)
```

This will return a date in the format you're after yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h) format (ODBC canonical, not ISO).

Answer (score 0):

the formatting of the datetime depends on the client. You can use the [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx) function to display it as a string in the format of your choice.