# Change single database datetime format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server which is on the US datetime format (`MM/dd/yyyy`) and I need to set only one database to default to the UK format (`dd/MM/yyyy`).

Is that something that is possible to do? Or does it need to be changed for the whole server?

The requirement is to leave the other databases to the US format. For SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You confuse data with its representation.

Comment: i know this might be another question .. but can we really change datetime format in SQL server .. means is SQL Server stores date as "02/21/2013" or "03/25/2013" .. or it will store "2013-03-25" and we need to change date format while displaying

Comment: A `DateTime` is **NOT** stored in any specific string format - it's a **8 byte** binary data blob without any formatting. The **display format** is only relevant for **displaying** the dates stored. So basically, you cannot change the SQL Server *`DateTime` format* - there is none - it's just stores as 8 bytes....

Comment: related: [How do I control the format in which MS-SQL Server returns datetime values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494640/how-do-i-control-the-format-in-which-ms-sql-server-returns-datetime-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), convert(date,'2013/10/18'), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
```